# Setting delegate for previewingGestureRecognizerForFailureRelationship throws an exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, 3dtouch

I'm trying to adopt UIViewController previewing (Peek & Pop with 3D Touch) using the following code:

```
id<UIViewControllerPreviewing> context = [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:self.imageView];
```

There's a property in protocol `UIViewControllerPreviewing`, `previewingGestureRecognizerForFailureRelationship`, which is actually an instance of `UIGestureRecognizer`, confused me a lot.

As the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollerpreviewing/1621467-previewinggesturerecognizerforfa?language=objc) said:

> Use this gesture recognizer by implementing a delegate object for it that conforms to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol.

However, when I set the `delegate` for `previewingGestureRecognizerForFailureRelationship`,

```
context.previewingGestureRecognizerForFailureRelationship.delegate = self;
```

A error occurred:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You cannot change the delegate of the UIViewControllerPreviewing failure relationship gesture recognizer'

So how to use this property?

Answer (score 2):

Seems I'm a few months late on this, but it still may help someone in the future.

When you call [`registerForPreviewing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621463-registerforpreviewing) on your view controller, you get back a context object that conforms to the [`UIViewControllerPreviewing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrollerpreviewing) protocol. You can store a reference to that context's `previewingGestureRecognizerForFailureRelationship` for use in your `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods, or for requiring other gestures to fail.

```
//When registering for previewing
let previewingContext = self.registerForPreviewing(with delegate: self, sourceView: self.view)
self.previewingGestureRecognizer = previewingContext. previewingGestureRecognizerForFailureRelationship

//Requiring failure for another gesture to be recognized
let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(handleLongPress(_ :)))
longPressGesture.require(toFail: self.previewingGestureRecognizer)
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```